# 'serialWrite' was not declared in this scope

Tags: library

Please help me! Once I click the upload button.
I get the following error:

> 'serialWrite' was not declared in this scope

Here is my code:

```c
int buttonPin
void setup ()
{
beginSerial(9600);
pinMode (buttonPin, INPUT);
}
void loop ()
{
if (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
serialWrite('H');
else
serialwrite('L');
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Where did you see that anything called "serialWrite" is supposed to exist?

Comment: Pay attention to the examples. They would have had `Serial.begin (9600);` - not `beginSerial(9600);`. You can't just re-arrange words and drop off punctuation.

Comment: Also, `int buttonPin` won't compile.

Comment: Same code! After I upload it. It was an error.  avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout (something like that